# Integrating in Python

Tags: python

I've been meaning to integrate in python, but I don't use Scipy, Numpy, or none of any other programs which go can be integrated into python. I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to coding, but I need help integrating. I've copied a small code but I still need to improve it.

```
def LeftEndSum(startingx, endingx, numberofRectangles) :

    width = (float(endingx) - float(startingx)) / numberofRectangles

    runningSum = 0

    for i in range(numberofRectangles) :
        height = f(startingx + i*width)
        area = height * width
        runningSum += area
    return runningSum
```

I'm trying to integrate, but i want to get a list of data points that I can then graph into a plot at the end of the integration

I had an idea of defining an interval [a,b] and a delta n=(a change in # boxes between points), where I can do a convergence test in order to stop the loop to get the points. the convergence test would go

if I (n(old value)+delta(n))-I (n(old value))/I (n(old)) < epsilon
where epsilon=1x10^-6

in which if the integrated values the code breaks

Comment: That convergence test is purely heuristic. The fact that a finer mesh gives you an approximation which is close to the approximation given by a coarser mesh doesn't prove that these two approximations are close to the value being approximated. In any event -- it is easy enough to return two things in a Python value, both the value of a numerical integration and a list of function evaluations.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to integrate y = x*x from 0.0 to 10.0, we know the answer is 333.33333.  Here's some code to do that:

```
def y_equals_x_squared(x):
    y = x*x
    return y

def LeftEndSum(startingx, endingx, numberofRectangles) :
    width = (float(endingx) - float(startingx)) / numberofRectangles
    #print "width = " + str(width)
    runningSum = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= numberofRectangles:
        x = (endingx - startingx)/(numberofRectangles) * (i - 1) + startingx
        height = y_equals_x_squared(x)
        area = height * width
        #print "i, x , height, area = " + str(i) + ", " + str(x) + ", " + str(height) + ", " + str(area)
        runningSum += area
        i += 1
    return runningSum
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
startingx = 0.0 
endingx = 10.0 
#
numberofRectangles = 3
old_answer = LeftEndSum(startingx, endingx, numberofRectangles)
#
numberofRectangles = 4
new_answer = LeftEndSum(startingx, endingx, numberofRectangles)
#
delta_answer = abs(new_answer - old_answer)
#
tolerance = 0.0001
max_iterations = 500
iteration_count = 0
iterations = []
answers = []
while delta_answer > tolerance:
    numberofRectangles += 100
    new_answer = LeftEndSum(startingx, endingx, numberofRectangles)
    delta_answer = abs(new_answer - old_answer)
    old_answer = new_answer
    iteration_count += 1
    iterations.append(iteration_count)
    answers.append(new_answer)
    print "iteration_count, new_answer = " + str(iteration_count) + ", " + str(new_answer)
    if(iteration_count > max_iterations):
        print "reached max_iterations, breaking"
        break
#
OutputFile = "Integration_Results.txt"
with open(OutputFile, 'a') as the_file:
    for index in range(len(answers)):
        the_file.write(str(index) + " " + str(answers[index]) + "\n")
#
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(iterations, answers, 'r-', label = "Increasing # Rectangles")
title_temp = "Simple Integration"
plt.title(title_temp, fontsize=12, fontweight='bold', color='green')
ax.legend(loc='best', ncol=1, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
plt.xlabel('Number of Iterations')
plt.ylabel('Answer') 
ax.grid(True)
plt.show(block=True)
```

Notice we plot the answer versus number of iterations at the end and it approaches the real answer very slowly as the number of iterations increase. There are other integration methods that will do better than simple rectangles such as the trapezoidal rule.  When you put in a while loop and check for a tolerance always put in a max_iterations check so you don't get stuck in an infinite loop.

You can check your answer here:
http://www.integral-calculator.com/
That's how we know the answer is 333.3333

Comment: Sorry to bother you but i tried running the code but it says there's a syntax error in line 37 I believe "  print "iteration_count, new_answer = " + str(iteration_count) + ", " + str(new_answer)" is the line where it says invalid syntax and highlights the double quotation after the equal sign.

Comment: I have noticed that when you copy code from the internet that sometimes the quotes don't get copied correctly.  You can try deleting the double quote and typing the double quote back.

Comment: Nvm i got it I was just missing parentheses, since I'm running Python 3.44

Comment: One last thing, I would really appreciate it if you could help me out with this last thing, is there anyway I can make a table with the values that are recorded in the answers[ ] section like can i append it to a list. Thanks

Comment: If you want to see the results rather than plot them you can simply say:
print iterations
print answers

Comment: I tried but all it does is print "[ ]" twice. Is there any way i can make it into a list in another file?

Comment: You could try writing the results to a file after you finished iterating like this:
'code'
#
OutputFile = "Integration_Results.txt"
with open(OutputFile, 'a') as the_file:
    for index in range(len(answers)):
        the_file.write(str(index) + " " + str(answers[index]) + "\n")
#
'code'

Comment: @J.Garcia I couldn't get the formatting right in the last response, so I edited my answer so you can see it better.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCHH!!! You just saved my life. I can't thank you enough. You're nothing short of a genius

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to include `f` as a parameter in the function. Why hardwire in a fixed formula? Furthermore, the code can be drastically simplified by using the built-in function `sum` applied to a generator:

```
def riemannSum(f,a,b,n,sample = 'L'):
    """computes Riemann sum of f over [a,b] using n rectangles and left ('L'), right ('R') or midpoints ('M')"""
    h = (b-a)/float(n)
    if sample.upper() == 'L':
        s = a #s = first sample point
    elif sample.upper() == 'R':
        s = a + h
    else:
        s = a + h/2.0
    return h*sum(f(s+i*h) for i in range(n))
```

You can define functions explicitly and then integrate them:

```
>>> def reciprocal(x): return 1/x

>>> riemannSum(reciprocal,1,2,100)
0.6956534304818242
```

(the exact value is the natural log of 2, which is approximately 0.693147)

Or, you can use anonymous functions (lambda expressions):

```
>>> riemannSum(lambda x: x**2,0,1,100,'m')
0.333325
```

Or, you can use functions already in the `math` module:

```
>>> riemannSum(math.sin,0,math.pi,10)
1.9835235375094546
```

None of these methods are very accurate. A more accurate on is [Simpson's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_rule) which is also pretty easy to do in Python:

```
def simpsonsRule(f,a,b,n):
    if n%2 == 1:
        return "Not applicable"
    else:
        h = (b-a)/float(n)
        s = f(a) + sum((4 if i%2 == 1 else 2)*f(a+i*h) for i in range(1,n)) + f(b)
        return s*h/3.0
```

For example:

```
>>> simpsonsRule(math.sin,0,math.pi,10)
2.0001095173150043
```

This is much more accurate than the Riemann sum with 10 rectangles (the true value is 2).